# Periodical chess problems by RSS

Tags: chess

Is there somehow I can find an RSS feed of daily chess problems at different difficulties? I like chess and would like to get reminded to practice now and then.

Update: I've found [Brian's Daily Chess Pouzzles](http://www.dailychesspuzzles.com/), but they're all too easy, almost all of them 2-3 moves to mate or win heavy material.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an RSS feed, but if you're after Chess puzzles, in addition to the daily puzzle and free tactics, Chess.com also has a variety of subscription options that offer unlimited daily tactics puzzles (and computer workouts).

If you then download the Chess.com app for your smartphone, iOS or Android, (or set up email alerts), you will can be reminded with notifications (in addition to having an endless and expansive Chess resource). Not RSS, but a considerably better alternative I think.

Answer (score 2):

Again, not an RSS feed, but ... one of my favorite sources of chess puzzles is http://ChessTempo.com

Much like chess.com, but doesn't have the 3 puzzle/day limit.  Also has endgame technique puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

No knowledge of the area whatsoever, but a bit of quick googling turned up [this page](http://www.chess.com/forum/category/daily-puzzles), which appears to have an [RSS feed](http://www.chess.com/rss/forums/daily-puzzles). Maybe that's the kind of thing you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will give an RSS feed but [Chess.com](http://www.chess.com) has a daily puzzle along with 3 targeted tactical problems per day for free users.

Answer (score 1):

I subscribe to "*Daily Chess Puzzles* - *Chess*.com" and the puzzles start easy on Sunday and get progressively harder until Saturday, where they're the most difficult.